# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError undefined input parameter

Tags: angular

Going round in circles on how to fix this.  Read the two blogs highlighted everywhere.  Understand the reason but doesn't matter what i try, this error will not go away.  The error is with the input parameter.  When the component loads, it's undefined and then gets the correct value.

I've tried using:

- various lifecycle hooks in the sub component with no luck - ngOnit,
- ngAfterViewChecked, ngAfterViewInit etc.
- Tried using a timer
- Tried using ChangeDetectorRef in the sub component
- Tried using *ngIf="ComponentName"
- EventEmitter to true to allow async

I still get the error.  Can someone please see what i am doing wrong please.

**Error Message**

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'AreaName: undefined'. Current value: 'AreaName: dashboard'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

**Parent Component ts file.**

```
export class Dashboard {
  public ComponentName: string = "dashboard";
  private showContent: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  public displayMethod(): void {}

  public CanAccess(canAccess : boolean) : boolean {
    return this.showContent = canAccess;
  }
}
```

**Parent Component Html**

```
<div class="content-area" >
   <h3>This is dashboard information</h3> 
</div>

<no-access [AreaName]="ComponentName" (AllowedAccess)="CanAccess($event)"></no-access>
```

**SubComponent ts**

```
export class NoAccess implements OnInit {

    @Input() AreaName: string;
    @Output() AllowedAccess = new EventEmitter<boolean>(true);
    public showSubContent: boolean;

    constructor(private authService : AuthenticationService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showSubContent = this.authService.CanRead(this.AreaName, null);
        this.AllowedAccess.emit(false);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the child component has been created before the parent component. Is the NoAccess component used elsewhere ?

Comment: No, this is the first instance, but it will be used elsewhere.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put together a StackBlitz or something demonstrating the issue. I put together this one using the source you posted and it seems to be working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bq9quj

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
export class Dashboard {
  public ComponentName: string = "dashboard";
  private showContent: boolean = false;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  public displayMethod(): void {}

  public CanAccess(canAccess : boolean) : boolean {
    return this.showContent = canAccess;
  }
}
```

Not the best solution imho, as described here https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4#c2ba, but it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, i still get the same error.  I did read that blog post.